# Comma separated List in linq select

Tags: c#, linq

I have Table HR_Travel(TravelID, TravelCode....) and HR_TravelDocuments(TravelDocID, TravelID, DocUrl)

```
        FromDate = FromDate.AddDays(1);
        ToDate = ToDate.AddDays(1);
        List<dynamic> Lst = new List<dynamic>();

        var queryTravelDetails = from t in db.HR_TravelDetails
                                 where ((t.StatusDate >= FromDate && t.StatusDate <= ToDate)
                                 && (t.EmpID == EmpID || EmpID == 0) && (t.TravelStatus == TravelStatus || TravelStatus == "All"))
                                 orderby t.StatusDate descending
                                 select new 
                                 {
                                     TravelID = t.TravelID,
                                     TravelSubID = db.HR_TravelDetails.Where(i => i.TravelID == 0).FirstOrDefault().TravelID == null ? 0 : db.HR_TravelDetails.Where(i => i.TravelID == 0).FirstOrDefault().TravelID,
                                     t.TravelCode,
                                     t.EmpID,
                                     EmpName = db.EE_Employee.Where(i => i.EmpID == t.EmpID).FirstOrDefault().EmpName,
                                     t.CellNo,
                                     t.BoardingForm,
                                     t.DestinationTO,
                                     t.JournyDate,
                                     t.Purpose,
                                     t.Organization,
                                     t.TravelStatus,

                                     DocUrl = DocUrl = string.Join(",",( db.HR_TravelDocuments.Where(i => i.TravelID == t.TravelID && i.TravelSubID == 0).Select(i => i.DocUrl).ToList()))
                                 };

  foreach (var element in queryTravelDetails)
        {
            Lst.Add(element);              
        }
```

Gives the following error:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join[String](System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

Comment: If Linq-To-Whatever does not support it you could materialize it to a Linq-To-Objects query, then you can use whatever you like. You just have to add `AsEnumerable` after the `Where`. Then it loads into memory.

Comment: He does use string.Join( for DocUrl, i guess you cannot perform a Join inside the anonymous column definitions, before you actually have the data as a tolist().

Comment: I tried to use AsEnumerable after where but still same eoor is cming when I write simply 
            string DocUrl = string.Join(",", (db.HR_TravelDocuments.Where(i => i.TravelID == 1 && i.TravelSubID == 0).Select(i => i.DocUrl).ToList()));                                                         works fine

Answer (score 0):

The Join() method can't be used in LINQ expressions, because it cannot translate from CLR to T-SQL. Another example is that you can't use:

```
var itemCount = db.Table.Count(p => p.Something == SomeFunction(someVariable));
```

You should move the method call outside the LINQ statement:

```
var anotherVariable = SomeFunction(someVariable);
var itemCount = db.Table.Count(p => p.Something == anotherVariable);
```

I hope I explained in a good way.

EDIT: As seen in the comments before, you can also use ToArray() and when the data is loaded locally you can use functions in statements freely.